# Using liblinear in Python

Tags: python, libsvm

I am using Python33, I downloaded Liblinear and copy liblinear.py and liblinearutil.py into $python$\libs\site-packages\ and the liblinear.dll into my C:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\sysWOW64.

However, when I run `from liblinearutil import *`, it says it cannot find the dll.

But the weired thing is that if I set a breakpoint in ctypes\util.py this line:

```
if os.path.isfile(fname):
            return fname
```

it seems it can find that dll. but when read it, it says it's not a valid win32 blah

How can I set this up?